# Spacing between displayed query result

Tags: php, mysql, echo, spacing

I am new to php and MySQL.

I am making a script on my website, that deals with mobile downloads.

I have 3 tables set up that I am dealing with here.

1. downloads (contains info about a specific download, each with its own id).
2. models (contains a list a possible device models(model names), each with its own id).
3. downloads_models (linking table stating download_id = model_id, eg. (1,2) (1,3) (2,1)).

I have a simple query to display the models that support each specific download. It goes as follows:

```
    $dlDetailsQuery = 'SELECT models.model
    FROM models,downloads_models
    WHERE downloads_models.modId = models.model_id
    AND downloads_models.downId = "'.$pageId.'"
    ORDER BY models.model ASC; 
    ';
```

To display which models support the download, this line is `echo`d:

```
    $dpModSupport .= stripslashes($row['model']);
```

Now as an example, my page has a $pageId of "1" which is the download "example1", "example1" supports models 1(model1), 2(model2) and 3(model3). When`$dpModSupport` is `echo`d, it echoes as `"model1model2model3"`.

My question is this: how do I get spacing, or a comma between the results?

What I am aiming for is an output of "model1, model2, model3".

I'm looking for a way to do this via php. I don't know whether a query can be structured to output spacing between results, so I'm guessing that php is the only solution there.

I do not want to add the spacing or commas into the model name field, or create a new field containing the spacing or commas along with the model's name.

Comment: What's this word "im" that keeps cropping up in questions lately? :(

Comment: 1) what is `$row`? Show us your real code. 2) Why `.=` and not just `=`?

Comment: @Tomalak: Blackberry requires all its clients to pass a maximum-literacy test?

Comment: @Kerrek: Hehe wouldn't surprise me

Comment: @Kerrek Will post the full code in a sec, but the .= is there because the download has more than one option, without the .= there, it simply outputs the first option only. Concatenation?

Comment: @Tomalak Forgive me for not growing up with the luxuries you seem to ignore. Not going to high school, along with living in a third world dust bowl has taken its toll on my grammar. I appologise for offending you in this manner :)

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Apology accepted, as long as you don't do it again. :) And don't assume any "luxuries" on my part; you don't know anything about me.

Comment: @Tomalak You're educated enough to use the grammar god has given us, but point taken.

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Yes, I have access to the World Wide Web... and so do you!

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Full code may not be necessary, just how you get from the query to `$row`. In any case, the solution should involve some sort of `implode` eventually, as in the answers below.

Comment: @Kerrek while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql4)) {

Comment: @Kerrek $sql4 = mysql_query($dlDetailsQuery) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

By writing this in a loop:

```
$dpModSupport .= stripslashes($row['model']);
```

you're building up a string like this:

```
$dpModSupport .= stripslashes(<MODEL1>);
$dpModSupport .= stripslashes(<MODEL2>);
$dpModSupport .= stripslashes(<MODEL3>);
```

thus ending up with a string that's just the contents of each row splattered next to each other.

---

### Solution

Instead, you could write this before your loop:

```
$dpModSupport = Array();
```

And then, inside it, instead of the line with `.=` building up a string, build up the array:

```
$dpModSupport[] = stripslashes($row['model']);
```

Finally, to obtain output consisting of each element of said array, joined by a comma:

```
echo implode(', ', $dpModSupport);
```

I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to look up these functions and language features in the PHP manual.

Comment: Thank you man, I appreciate that you took some time to help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Store the names in an array, and then join them at the end.

```
$dpModSupport = array();
$dpModSupport[] = stripslashes($row['model']);
echo implode(', ', $dpModSupport);
```